# How to create @login_required decorator for app engine class

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have this initialize function which sets self.user if user has logged

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def initialize(self, *a, **kw):
        webapp2.RequestHandler.initialize(self, *a, **kw)
        uid = self.read_secure_cookie('user_id')
        self.user = uid and User.by_id(int(uid))
```

I would like to create a decorator that redirect the user to the login page if she is not logged in:

```
def login_required(cls):
    if not self.user:
        self.redirect("/login")

@login_required
class Test(MainHandler)
    def get(self):
        self.write("this will only display if I am logged in")
```

When I tried the example abode, I get `'NameError: name 'login_required' is not defined'`

What am I missing?

Comment: There's plenty wrong with the code you've posted, but it wouldn't give the error that you show (you don't call anything named "authenticate").

Comment: Right, that was a mistake. login_required was called authenticate earlier. Have changed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this page useful in order to understand how decorators work: http://simeonfranklin.com/blog/2012/jul/1/python-decorators-in-12-steps/

Your decorator needs to call the handler after performing whatever task it needs to. Here is a variation of my current login_required decorator definition:

```
def login_required(handler):
    def check_login(self, *args, **kwargs):
        userToken = auth.get_auth().get_user_by_session()
        if not userToken:             
            logging.info('No user found for session: login required')
            return self.redirect(LOGIN_URL, abort=False)                    
        return handler(self, *args, **kwargs) # Call the handler method
    return check_login
```

The decorator in this case is applied to the instance method, not the class ie:

```
class Test(MainHandler)
    @login_required
    def get(self):
        ...
```